# Как перебрать каждые 3шт. элемента массива по отдельности, если внутри массиве 12 элементов?

Tags: javascript, html

При выборе сезона и нажатии на "Ок", во втором `select` должны добавляться те месяцы, которые относятся к выбранному времени года. 
Но условие в том, что нужно использовать два массива: один для времён года и второй для всех месяцев.
Есть ли еще варианты?

```js
       const month = document.getElementById("month");
       const season = document.getElementById("season");
       const display = document.getElementById("display")
       let pSeason = {};
       let pMonth = {};
       pMonth = ["Декабрь","Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь","Октябрь", "Ноябрь"];
       pSeason = ["Зима", "Весна", "Лето","Осень"]

       for(let i = 0; i < pSeason.length; i++){
        season.innerHTML += "<option>" + pSeason[i] + "</option>"
       }

       function ok() {
        month.innerHTML = "";
        display.innerHTML = "";
        
        if(season.value == pSeason[0] ){
          
            for(let i = 0; i < 3 ;i++){
                month.innerHTML += "<option>" + pMonth[i] + "</option>";
                
            }
         
        }else if(season.value == pSeason[1]){
         
            for(let i = 3; i < 6 ;i++){
               
                month.innerHTML += "<option>" + pMonth[i] + "</option>";
            }   
        }else if(season.value == pSeason[2]){
         
            for(let i = 6; i < 9  ;i++){
               
               month.innerHTML += "<option>" + pMonth[i] + "</option>";
           }   
        }else if(season.value == pSeason[3]){
        
         for(let i = 9; i < pMonth.length  ;i++){
            
            month.innerHTML += "<option>" + pMonth[i] + "</option>";
        }   
     }

       }
       function ok2(){
        
        display.innerHTML = `Выбран месяц ${month.value} (${season.value})`;
       }
```

```html
   <select name="" id="season"></select>
   <button onclick="ok()">ok</button>
   <select name="" id="month"></select>
  
   <button onclick="ok2()">ok</button>
   <p id="display"></p>
```

Comment: «условие в том, что нужно использовать два массива» (c) — Прямо условие задачи, или другая структура кроме массива не придумалась?) Потому что можно сделать объект `{ "зима": ["Декабрь", "Январь", "Февраль"], "лето": [ /***/ ] }`

Comment: Здравствуйте! Да, изначально я так и делал, но увы, в условии было сказано, что нужно сделать это все с помощью 2 массива ;(

Answer (score 3):

```js
const season = document.getElementById("season");
const month = document.getElementById("month");
const display = document.getElementById("display");
let pSeason = ["Зима", "Весна", "Лето", "Осень"];
let pMonth = ["Декабрь", "Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь"];

pSeason.forEach(el => {
  season.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<option>${el}</option>`);
})

function ok() {
  month.innerHTML = "";
  display.innerHTML = "";
  pMonth.slice(season.selectedIndex * 3, season.selectedIndex * 3 + 3).forEach(el => {
    month.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<option>${el}</option>`);
  })
}

function ok2() {
  display.innerHTML = `Выбран месяц ${month.value} (${season.value})`;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="season"></select>
<button onclick="ok()">ok</button>

<select name="" id="month"></select>
<button onclick="ok2()">ok</button>

<p id="display"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Первое решение основано, в основом, на CSS:

```js
const months = "Декабрь,Январь,Февраль,Март,Апрель,Май,Июнь,Июль,Август,Сентябрь,Октябрь,Ноябрь".split`,`;
const seasons = "Зима,Весна,Лето,Осень".split`,`;

const option = (ses,idx)=>`<option value="${idx}">${ses}</option>`;

season.innerHTML += seasons.map(option).join``;
month.innerHTML += months.map(option).join``;

style.innerHTML += [...months.keys()].map(
  idx => `#season[value="${~~(idx/3)}"]+#month>option:nth-child(${idx+2})`
).join`,` + '{display: list-item;}';

season.oninput = () => ([month.value,output.innerHTML]=[-1,''],
  season.setAttribute('value', season.value));   

month.oninput = () =>
  output.innerHTML = ! months[month.value] ? '' :
    'Вы выбрали: ' + seasons[season.value] + '/' + months[month.value];
```

```html
<select id="season"><option value="-1">Сезон</option></select>
<select id="month"><option value="-1">Месяц</option></select>
<output id="output"></output>
<style id="style">
  select { display: block; width: 10rem; height: 1.7rem; }
  #month > option { display:none; }
  #month > option:nth-child(1) { display: list-item; }
</style>
```

А здесь базовый вариант:

```js
const months = ["Декабрь","Январь","Февраль","Март","Апрель","Май","Июнь","Июль","Август","Сентябрь","Октябрь","Ноябрь"];
const seasons = ["Зима","Весна","Лето","Осень"];

season.innerHTML += seasons.map(
  (ses,idx)=>`<option value="${idx}">${ses}</option>`
).join``;

season.oninput = () => {
  output.innerHTML = '';
  month.innerHTML = '<option>Месяц</option>'+
    months.slice(season.value*3,season.value*3+3)
    .map(
      (mon,idx)=>`<option value="${season.value*3+idx}">${mon}</option>`
    ).join``;
};

month.oninput = () => {
  output.innerHTML = ! months[month.value] ? '' :
    'Вы выбрали: ' + 
      seasons[season.value] + '/' + 
      months[month.value];
};
```

```css
select { display: block; width: 10rem; height: 1.7rem; }
```

```html
<select id="season"><option>Сезон</option></select>
<select id="month"><option>Месяц</option></select>
<output id="output"></output>
```

А на radio-элементах можно так:

```js
const months = "Декабрь,Январь,Февраль,Март,Апрель,Май,Июнь,Июль,Август,Сентябрь,Октябрь,Ноябрь".split`,`;
const seasons = "Зима,Весна,Лето,Осень".split`,`;

document.body.innerHTML = seasons.map(
  (ses,idx)=>`<input type="radio" name="season" id="season_${idx}" value="${idx}">`
).join`\n` + months.map(
  (mon,idx)=>`<input type="radio" name="month" id="month_${idx}" value="${idx}">`
).join`\n`+'\n' + document.body.innerHTML;

fs_seasons.innerHTML += seasons.map(
  (ses,idx)=>`<label for="season_${idx}">${ses}</label>`
).join`\n`;

fs_months.innerHTML += months.map(
  (mon,idx)=>`<label for="month_${idx}">${mon}</label>`
).join`\n`;

output.innerHTML += seasons.map(
  (ses,idx)=>`<label id="season_label_${idx}">${ses}</label>`
).join`\n` +'\n'+ 
  `<span class="separator">/</span>`+'\n' + 
months.map(
  (mon,idx)=>`<label id="month_label_${idx}">${mon}</label>`
).join`\n`;

style.innerHTML += [...seasons.keys()].map(
  idx =>`#season_${idx}:checked~fieldset label[for="season_${idx}"]::before{content:"\\2705";}`
).join`\n`+'\n' + [...seasons.keys()].map(
  idx =>`#season_${idx}:checked~#output #season_label_${idx}{display:inline-block;}`
).join`\n`+'\n' + [...months.keys()].map(
  idx =>`#month_${idx}:checked~fieldset label[for="month_${idx}"]::before{content:"\\2705";}`
).join`\n`+'\n' + [...months.keys()].map(
  idx =>`#month_${idx}:checked~#output #month_label_${idx}{display:inline-block;}`
).join`\n` +'\n' + [...months.keys()].map(
  idx =>`#season_${~~(idx/3)}:checked~fieldset  label[for="month_${idx}"]{display:inline-block;}`
).join`\n`;

button.onclick = () => {
  let inner = document.body.innerHTML;
  inner = inner.substr(0,inner.indexOf('<script'));
  document.body.innerHTML += `<textarea onblur="this.remove()">${inner}</textarea>`;
  document.querySelector('textarea').focus(); 
  button.remove();
}
```

```html
<style id="style">
  input[type="radio"] { display:none }
  label { margin: 0 1rem 0 1rem; }
  #fs_seasons label::before, #fs_months label::before { content: "\1F532"; }
  #fs_months label { display: none; }
  #output label { display: none; }
  .separator { display: inline-block; margin: 0 1rem 0 1rem; }
  textarea { position: fixed; left: 10vw; top: 10vh; width: 80vw; height: 80vh; }
</style>
<fieldset id="fs_seasons"><legend>Сезон</legend></fieldset>
<fieldset id="fs_months"><legend>Месяц</legend></fieldset>
<fieldset id="output"><legend>Вы выбрали</legend></fieldset>
<button id="button">Покажи код</button>
```

Кстати, последнее решение работает полностью без JS. Тот JS, который там написан только для генерации HTML-кода. Сгенерированный HTML можно посмотреть нажав на кнопку.